# alert close when click button is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder what is wrong in this code, so the click event doesn't work on any DOM I have tried. Here is the code that I am using in WordPress plugin. The script is loading and even the first `alert('loaded')` is working too, but nothing works on the `click` event.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    alert('loaded');

    $('.gs-close').on('click', function () {
        // alert('clicked');
        $(this).hide();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Does something with the class `gs-close` exist in the page? You need to include a [mcve] with relevant JavaScript **and** HTML so people can help.

Comment: Okay, I found the reason. The JS was set in the head tag so wan't getting dom. So loading in footer fixed the issue. But the question is if I want to load in head tag how it will work.

Comment: @Herohtar I have found the reason.. please see my comment. Is there any way to keep js file in head and still it finds the DOM?

Comment: In that case you will need to wait until the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @Herohtar do you mean I must load the javascript in the footer or after DOM?

Comment: I mean, [use jQuery to wait](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score -1):

I checked the code its work but u have to disable the href event of the link when working with the a tag (link). hope it will work. plz provide example if its didn't work. so I can have a look :)

```
<pre>
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    alert('loaded');

    $('.gs-close').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert('clicked');
        $(this).hide();
    });

})(jQuery);
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kanun for the reference but I think you haven't understood the challenge I have. Please read back my question.

Comment: can u check 
console.log( $('.gs-close'));
check on browser console the item is showing or not